# Solving a Volterra Integral Equation with a Bessel Function

Tags: laplace-transform, bessel-functions, integral-equations

So, I am doing a project on Bessel Functions and one of the questions is:

Solve the following Volterra Integral Equation of the First Kind.

$$ \int_{0}^{x} J_{0}(x-t)y(t) dt = sin(x) $$

where,
$J_{0}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k!)^2} (\frac{x}{2})^{2k}$ is the Bessel Function of the First Kind.

Now, I know

$$ L(sin(t))(s) = \frac{1}{s^{2}+1} $$

But I am struggling to workout the integral with a summation and thus solve the equation.

Answer (score 4):

Well, we have the following equality:

$$\int_0^x\text{J}_0\left(x-t\right)\text{y}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=\sin\left(x\right)\tag1$$

Now, when we want to take the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) we need to use the time-domain integration property of the Laplace transform:

$$\frac{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\sqrt{1+\text{s}^2}}=\frac{1}{1+\text{s}^2}\tag2$$

So:

$$\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{1+\text{s}^2}}{1+\text{s}^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\text{s}^2}}\tag3$$

Which gives:

$$\text{y}\left(t\right)=\text{J}_0\left(t\right)\tag4$$

Comment: Ok, but could you explain how you got the left hand side (the integration) in a bit more detail?